# Building a telegram channel Bot that will send a welcome message to new users privately

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I just started using python. I am trying to build a telegram channel Bot that will send a welcome message to new users privately. Other users should not get spammed by these messages, therefore I  want the bot to send it only to the new.

Each time i run my code, it come up with an error and I have spent hours trying to figure out . Could someone help pls. I want to fix the error . alternative if someone can guide me through that will be much appreciated

**here is error message** : NameError: name 'Filters' is not defined. Did you mean: 'filter'?

**here is my code**

```
import telegram

from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, CallbackContext

# Define a function to send the welcome message
def welcome(update: telegram.Update, context: CallbackContext):
user = update.message.from_user
chat_id = update.message.chat_id

# Customize your welcome message here
welcome_message = f"Hello {user.first_name}! Welcome to our channel. Here is a link to the    ebook: [https://www.example.com]"

# Send the welcome message privately to the user
context.bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text=welcome_message)


def main():
# Initialize the Telegram Bot
bot = telegram.Bot(token="xxxxx")
updater = Updater(bot, update_queue=None)

# Create a new filter that matches new users
new_user_filter = Filters.new_chat_members()

# Create a command handler to trigger the welcome message
dispatcher = updater.dispatcher
dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler("welcome", welcome))

# Add the new user filter to the command handler
dispatcher.add_handler(new_user_filter, welcome)

# Start the bot
updater.start_polling()
updater.idle()

if __name__ == "__main__":
main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to import `filters` from `telegram.ext`.

First add `filters` to your `from telegram.ext` line:

```
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, CallbackContext, filters
```

Then for the [`NEW_CHAT_MEMBERS`](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/v20.5/telegram.ext.filters.html#telegram.ext.filters.StatusUpdate.NEW_CHAT_MEMBERS) filter, use:

```
# Create a new filter that matches new users
new_user_filter = filters.StatusUpdate.NEW_CHAT_MEMBERS
```

Comment: Thank you very much .  I make some changes as suggest above and it return another error .  AttributeError: 'Updater' object has no attribute 'dispatcher'